# VueJS for loop creating components, components seem to be linked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm doing a for loop on an array, for each value i'm creating a component. I was under the impression that I need to put a `key` on the for loop so that Vue knows it is unique?

```
<div v-for="hours in location.hours" class="businessHours" :key="hours.id">
    <business-hours :response="hours" :unique-key="uniqueKey" :default-weekdays="response.weekdays">
        <div slot-scope="{ hours, weekdays, title, uniqueKey, toggle, inArray, componentKey }">

            <div class="panel-heading v-center">
                <div class="field">
```

Within this component I have got some logic that just selects/deselected checkboxes, however these 2 components seem to be linked. When I click checkboxes on one of them, the other one changes too!

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot :hours="response" :weekdays="weekdays" :title="title" :toggle="toggle" :inArray="inArray" :componentKey="componentKey"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        props: [ 'response', 'uniqueKey', 'defaultWeekdays' ],
        data: function() {
            return {
                weekdays: this.response.weekdays,
                componentKey: this.key()
            }
        },
        created() {
            if (this.weekdays === undefined) {
                this.weekdays = this.defaultWeekdays;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            title: function() {

                if (this.weekdays === undefined) return;

                let selected = Object.keys(this.weekdays).filter((e) => { if (this.weekdays[e].selected) return e });

                if (selected.length === 0) return;

                let start = this.weekdays[parseInt(selected[0])].value;
                let end = this.weekdays[parseInt(selected[selected.length - 1])].value;

                if (start === end) {
                    return start.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + start.substring(1);
                }
                return start.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + start.substring(1) + ' - ' + end.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + end.substring(1);
            },
            toggle: function(index) {

                let clicked = this.weekdays[index];
                let action = clicked.selected ? 'remove' : 'add';
                let selected = Object.keys(this.weekdays).filter((i) => { if (this.weekdays[i].selected) return i });

                let start = parseInt(selected[0]);
                let middle = parseInt(selected[Math.floor(selected.length / 2)]);
                let end = parseInt(selected[selected.length - 1]);

                if (isNaN(start) && isNaN(middle) && isNaN(end)) {
                    start = middle = end = index;
                }

                // Add and remove multiple days
                if (index < (start - 1) && action === 'add') {
                    for (let i = index; i <= (start - 1); i++) {
                        this.weekdays[i].selected = true;
                    }
                }
                if (index > start && index < middle && action === 'remove') {
                    for (let i = start; i <= index; i++) {
                        this.weekdays[i].selected = false;
                    }
                }

                if (index > (end + 1) && action === 'add') {
                    for (let i = end + 1; i <= index; i++) {
                        this.weekdays[i].selected = true;
                    }
                }
                if (index < end && index >= middle && action === 'remove') {
                    for (let i = index; i <= end; i++) {
                        this.weekdays[i].selected = false;
                    }
                }

                // Add and remove single days
                if ((index === (end + 1) || index === (start - 1)) || (index === end || index === start) && action === 'add') {
                    this.weekdays[index].selected = true;
                }
                if ((index === end || index === start) && action === 'remove') {
                    this.weekdays[index].selected = false;
                }
            },
            inArray: function(needle) {
                let length = this.weekdays.length;
                for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if(this.weekdays[i] === needle) return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
            key: function() {
                return Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '').substr(0, 10);
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Can someone lend me a hand here as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try adding `key` on the component element itself?

Comment: Yeah, tried that :)

Comment: What is uniqueKey for? This doesnt look very unique :unique-key="uniqueKey", youre just passing some static variable here

Comment: Also youre passing the same reference to an object here: :default-weekdays="response.weekdays" I dont know where "response" comes from, but youre basically modifying the same object pointer on all your components. Try making a copy of it default-weekdays="{...response.weekdays}" so that each component has a unique copy

Comment: Additionally, move "weekdays" from data to a computed property since it depends on a prop being passed or not. Im not 100% sure but it looks like youre falling into this IF every time because of how you declared it  if (this.weekdays === undefined) {

Comment: PSSS. :key is a performance hint for vue so that it doesnt have to re render the whole list every time, and wont cause the problem you have. You have an issue with how your data is being handled, because of what I said in my second comment. Youre modifying pointers, not copies of the object. :)

Comment: @MarinaMosti The unique key is the parent component key which I use to ensure any emitted events are only picked up by the parent. I have renamed this to parent key to remove confusion.

Comment: @MarinaMosti I have changed default-weekdays to `:default-weekdays="{ ...response.weekdays }"`, no change. Have a quick read of my component, you will see that if the passed in `response` contains `weekdays` it will use this, however if it's a new address then it will not contain weekdays, so it will have to use the defaults.

Comment: @MarinaMosti The issue is defiantly with passing the default weekdays in, as I just put the weekdays array within my component directly rather than passing it in. However really I do need to pass them in, but `{ ...response.weekdays }` doesn't seem to make a copy?

Comment: `let clone = JSON.stringify(this.defaultWeekdays);
this.weekdays = JSON.parse(clone);`

This solved the issue.